# I can't use new in C++ function to build

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to new a space for a argument in this function.

```
void Binary::PreAndMid(Qnode* root, char temp1[], char temp2[], int m, int n, int j, int k) {
    if (n - m != k - j || m > n || j > k) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        root = new Qnode;  /*in other function the root is become null*/
        root->val = temp1[m];
        cout << root->val << endl;
        int f = Find(temp2, temp1[m]);
        if (f == -1) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            PreAndMid(root->LC, temp1, temp2, m + 1, m + f - j, j, f - 1);
            PreAndMid(root->RC, temp1, temp2, m + f - j + 1, n, f + 1, k);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is that the root is null.

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you need to do `*& root` so that the new memory address is returned at the end. Right now you are breaking the rule never use assignment operator on parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The argument `root` is passed in as a copy of the pointer. Assigning a new value to this pointer will not carry over after returning from the function.

If you want to this, you would need to pass the pointer `root` by reference:
`Qnode* &root`, which will make sure both the code calling this function and the function itself use the same variable.